# Let a $\in \mathbb R$ and consider the vector subspace $W$ of V=$\mathbb R^4$ vector >generated (1,1,1.2) , (1.0,1.1), (3,2,3,5) and (3.1,a,4).

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, vectors

> Let a $\in \mathbb R$ and consider the vector subspace $W$ of V=$\mathbb R^4$  vector >generated  (1,1,1.2) , (1.0,1.1), (3,2,3,5) and (3.1,a,4).
>
> Choose an option:
>
> A. if a$\ne$3, so W has dimension 4
>
> B. if a=2, so W has dimension 2
>
> C. if a=3, so W has dimension 2
>
> D. if a=3, so W has dimension 3
>
> E. if a$\ne$2, so W has dimension 3

what have i done so far

a+b+3c+3d=0

a+2c+d=0

a+b+3c+kd=0

2a+b+5c+4d=0

c=$\frac{1}{3}$(b-2a) and d=$\frac{1}{3}$(a-2b) and k=3.

So k=3, dim 2 the answer is c .

I already appreciate any assistance

Comment: How did you get $k = 3$?

Comment: Let $P=(1,1,1,2), Q=(1,0,1,1), R=(3,2,3,5).$ Then $R=2P+Q$ so $W$ is generated by at most $3$ linearly independent vectors, regardless of the value of "$a$" so option A is false. I cannot comment on your work as you have not said what $b,c,d,k$ are nor how your equations are obtained.